# 0.1 刻みのデータから特定の値だけが取り出せない

Tags: python, pandas

pandasを使い、0~0.9までの値を0.1刻みで取り出そうとしているのですが、
なぜか0.6だけ取り出すことができません。
0.6は存在することを確認しましたが、取り出すことができません。

```
aa = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(10):
    aa = aa.append((b[b["Gate Voltage[V]"] == 0.100*i]))
aa
```

実行結果
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

bのデータフレーム内には0.6の値は格納されていますが、なぜか表示されません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

0.6の列のコピです。

```
0.600   1.898000e-10    -3.000000e-14   -1.894200e-10   3.010000e-12    2.200000e-12    0.0 forward 0.0 6.305648e+01    0.0 inf 10  10  rgb(133.0614857142856,87.03999999999999,220.16)
```

---

追記

```
aa = aa.append((b[b["Gate Voltage[V]"] == round(0.1*i,1)]))
```

ご指摘の通りに実行しますと、0.7の時が表示されません。
0.7も存在することを確認済みです。（追記前には見えていました）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

追記

```
zzz = pd.DataFrame()
b = df_resistor[0][df_resistor[0]["Body Resistance"] == a[0]]
za = b[b["Gate Voltage[V]"] == 0.7]
za
zzz = zzz.append(za)
za = b[b["Gate Voltage[V]"] == 0.9]
zzz = zzz.append(za)
za = b[b["Gate Voltage[V]"] == 0.8]
zzz = zzz.append(za)
zzz
```

このプログラムを実行しても、0.7の時は表示されません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 精度(precision)の問題かと思われますので、整数値にして比較してみてはどうでしょうか。`aa = aa.append((b[int(b["Gate Voltage[V]"]*1000) == i*100]))`

Comment: すいません、勘違いでした。御指摘の通りに実行してもうまくいきません。

Comment: `aa = aa.append((b[(b["Gate Voltage[V]"]*1000).astype("int") == i*100]))`でうまくいきました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: `astype("int")` ですね。素晴らしいです。ぜひ自己回答してください。

Answer (score 2):

```
aa = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(6, 11):
    aa = aa.append((b[(b["Gate Voltage[V]"]*1000).astype("int") == i*100]))
# aaaa = aa.append((b[b["Gate Voltage[V]"] == round(0.1*i,1)]))
aa
```

とすることで上手く動きました。
小数点が悪さをしていたようです。

metropolisさん、akira ejiriさん
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

`0.100*i`では0.1刻みにならないと思います。

```
aa = aa.append((b[b["Gate Voltage[V]"] == 0.100*i]))
```

を

```
aa = aa.append((b[round(b["Gate Voltage[V]"],1) == round(0.100*i,1)]))
```

のように修正してはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 実行しましたが上手く機能しませんでした。

Comment: 比較する左辺も四捨五入するとどうなりますか？回答も修正しました。

Comment: 左辺こんな感じでは `b["Gate Voltage[V]"].round(1)`

Comment: @oriri 「b["Gate Voltage[V]"].round(1)」の方が読みやすいですね。また、回答の誤りに気付きました。コメントありがとうございました。

Comment: Pandas の round() メソッドは `round to even` なのでご注意を。また、Python3 の組み込み関数である round() も `round to even` です。

Comment: 組み込み関数 `round()` は `number.__round__` に移譲しているようです。で, 調べていくうち問題点見つかりました。`v = pd.Series([0.005,0.015,0.025,0.035,0.045,0.055,0.065,0.075]); round(v,2) == [round(n,2)for n in v]` でところどころ異なります。なので整数で扱うか, decimalモジュール使うかがよいかもです

Comment: もしくは numpy の find_nearest() がよいでしょう。